# Why will c++ assert() function brings overhead to program

Tags: c++, assert

I have the practice to use c++ assert to check if the program is running normally, such as this:

```
cv::Mat im = imread("pic.jpg")
assert(!im);
```

This would check if the image is read correctly. This is useful since the image might not be correctly placed in the expected directory, so we need to check. I feel that using `assert` is convenient, but people say that using `assert` would bring overhead to the program, and the suggestion is not using them. Why `assert` will bring overhead ? What is the good practice to check in this case ?

Comment: `assert()` will only do *anything* unless `-DNDEBUG` is set. It is a *debugging* feature, basically an `if ( ! (!im) ) { abort() }` wrapped in a `#ifndef NDEBUG`. Who says it will "bring overhead"?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are talking about std::assert, correct? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert

Comment: Your use of `assert` is problematic. I presume it "works" for you because you don't build in release configurations. Once `NDEBUG` is set, the assertion basically doesn't exist in your program. It means that a failed read is not going to be checked, and your program will try to use an invalid image. This sort of check doesn't belong in an assertion.

Comment: BTW, `std:asert` fails if the condition is FALSE. So in your case, it will fail if the `cv::Mat` is correctly loaded.

Comment: There is no `std::assert`; in the `#include <cassert>` header there is an `assert` macro.  Macro's are not part of a namespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, `assert()` is not an ordinary function. It is macro that looks similar to this:

```cpp
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define assert(condition) ((void)0)
#else
#define assert(condition) /*implementation*/
#endif
```

and as you see it is only enabled and doing something when `NDEBUG` is not defined. It is meant to be used to do **extra** checks on your program when you run in **debug mode** to help pinpoint errors (e.g. wrong arguments, invariants that don't hold, etc.) faster.

Assert itself probably doesn't cost that much performance if you use it as you shown but because of what I wrote above - it being debugging tool - might be used in many places of codebase. If conditions passed to assert are complex, sure it might take time to evaluate them (and your customers don't need to worry because this will only happen in debug mode, so they will be unaffected - with `NDEBUG` all that overhead will go away).

You should not use `assert()` to validate things you want **always** validated (also in non-debug mode). In this case it is correct to do:

```
cv::Mat im = imread("pic.jpg")
if (!im) {
   /* handle error ... */
}
```

Comment: Will std::assert brings overhead to the program, or just same as `if(....) {abort();}` ?

Comment: @CoinCheung In release builds it is as-if the `assert` was manually removed from the code before compiling.

Comment: @CoinCheung I feel you've skipped over the part of this answer that explains `assert` is not appropriate here. `assert` should never be used to check for something that can fail. It should only be used to check that something you already know is always `true` is actually `true`.

Comment: @CoinCheung -- there is no `std::assert`, just plain `assert`. As this answer says, it's a macro. Macros are not affected by scopes or namespaces.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux So, is the correct method is `if(!condition) {cout << "log msg\n"; exit();}` ?

Comment: @CoinCheung Yes, that's the correct way to check the `condition` that is needed to be true in runtime but sometimes might not be (which is your case - e.g. when picture file is missing, has different name, wrong format, etc.). `assert` should be only used for debugging purposes to avoid bugs in program by confirming something you know always should be `true` is actually `true` (that's why you can completely disable `assert` by `-DNDEBUG` once you done with debugging).

Comment: @CoinCheung That would be a possible way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

> Why will c++ assert() function brings overhead to program

Firstly, `assert` is technically not a function. It is a macro.

To answer the question: It depends. If assertions are disabled, then there will be no check and thus no overhead. If assertions are enabled, then yes there will be overhead compared to not having the check (unless compiler can prove at compile time that the check is unnecessary).

Answer (score 1):

Any additional code will add "overhead" to a program, as in adding execution time, code size, possibly ram size.
The same is true for code which uses `assert()` (apart from the detail that `assert()` only does its job and only uses any resources if active, i.e. if `-DNDEBUG` is not used; credits to DevSolar for this detail).

Both kinds of code, with and without `assert()`, are nevertheless added to programs, because of course they do serve a purpose.

You have described the purpose of using `assert()` clearly and adequatly.
Now the question is not whether it uses any resources, it is do you want to achieve the purpose, for which you are probably willing to pay the price of used resources.
Since you seem quite clear about the benefits, it seems an adequate decision to use `assert()`.

In case you are asking for any alternatives to using `assert()` the answer is that there are none which support the same purpose WITHOUT using any resources.

You might also want to consider that in cases you do not need the selfchecking features anymore (in my opinion that is usually never) and really focus on the "no overhead", then you can use the mentioned switch to remove the resource consumption.